# remove warnings from keras model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am getting warnings when constructing my model -- I don't think this was true at first; perhaps things have changed:

model:

```
# Initialise Sequential model
regressor = Sequential()

# units is the output dimensionality
# return sequences will return the sequence
# which will be required to the next LSTM 

# as a great big rule-o-thumb, layers should be less than 10, and perhaps 1 per endog plus 1 for all exog
# also see: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181/how-to-choose-the-number-of-hidden-layers-and-nodes-in-a-feedforward-neural-netw/1097#1097

alphaNh = len(columns) if len(columns) < 10 else 10 # 2-10, with 2 or 5 being common
sample_frames = n
nh = int(sample_frames/alphaNh*dim)

dropout = 0.2

print('nh', nh)  

# input shape will need only the last 2 dimensions
# of your input
################# 1st layer #######################
regressor.add(LSTM(units=nh, return_sequences=True, 
                   input_shape=(timesteps, dim)))

# add Dropout to do regulariztion
# standard practise to use 20%
# regressor.add(Dropout(dropout))

layers = (len(endog) + 1) if len(endog) > 1 else 2
print('layers', layers)
for i in range(1, layers):
  # After the first time, it's not required to 
  # specify the input_shape
  ################# layer #######################
#  if i > 5:
#      break
  if i < layers - 1:
    cell = LSTM(units=nh, return_sequences=True)
  else:
    cell = LSTM(units=nh)

  regressor.add(cell)

################# Dropout layer #################
# After training layers we use some dropout.
# another option is to put this after each dim 
# layer (above)
#
# standard practise to use 20%

regressor.add(Dropout(dropout))

################# Last layer ####################
# Last layer would be the fully connected layer,
# or the Dense layer
#
# The last word will predict a single number
# hence units=1

regressor.add(Dense(units=dim))

# Compiling the RNN
# The loss function for classification problem is 
# cross entropy, since this is a regression problem
# the loss function will be mean squared error

regressor.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')

### src: https://keras.io/callbacks/
#saves the model weights after each epoch if the validation loss decreased
###
checkpointer = ModelCheckpoint(filepath='weights.hdf5', verbose=1, monitor='loss', mode='min', save_best_only=True)
```

warnings:

```
nh 1400
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:263: colocate_with (from tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Colocations handled automatically by placer.
layers 3
WARNING:tensorflow:From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py:3445: calling dropout (from tensorflow.python.ops.nn_ops) with keep_prob is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Please use `rate` instead of `keep_prob`. Rate should be set to `rate = 1 - keep_prob`.
```

How can I modernize this (getting rid of the warnings)?

Comment: You can try this : `tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)`

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal would you like to submit this as the answer? otherwise I may just delete the question

Comment: What do the warnings mean? I mean should I be worried that I am doing something wrong?

Comment: a deprecation notice means it works but will soon be removed. so if you are maintaining this code, you should replace it. but for a one off investigation, it's fine.

Comment: These warnings are about how Keras uses TensorFlow. The people who maintain Keras are the ones who can fix them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warnings in TensorFlow could be managed by the `tf.logging` module. To turn off the warnings you can use,

```
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.ERROR)
```

Answer (score 11):

In TensorFlow 2 it is

```
tf.get_logger().setLevel('ERROR')
```